# Spring: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat

I tried following a tutorial for Spring but I can't get my app working on Tomcat. Every link I try is a 404 with the following error:

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target
> resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

I tried every possible combination of url. Here's my code. Even by copy-pasting the tutorial it doesn't work.

**StudentController.java**

```
package com.learningspring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView student(){
        return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Student());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addStudent( @ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") Student student, ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
        model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
        model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());

        return "result";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id = "WebApp_ID" version = "2.4"
         xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Form Handling</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>StudentSpring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StudentSpring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**StudentSpring-servlet.xml**

```
    <beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    
        <context:component-scan base-package = "com.learningspring" />
    
        <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
            <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
        </bean>
    
    </beans>
```

**student.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Student Information</h2>
    <form:form method="post" action="/HelloWeb/addStudent">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="id">ID</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**result.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@page isELIgnored = "false" %>
<%@taglib uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix = "form"%>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Submitted Student Information</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>${name}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>${age}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>${id}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will note that your tutorial is seriously outdated and recommend that you start with Spring Boot instead of dealing with wars and containers manually (and also recommend Thymeleaf as a replacement for JSP). One of Boot's main features is that it handles a lot of this tedious mapping for you automatically.

Comment: I agree, nobody uses web.xml or jsps nowdays - try tutorials from Baeldung https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-tutorial

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- To use Boot I have to build a new project here: start.spring.io, right? I know the tutorial is old, but it was part of a list given to me by my future workplace as a preparation for the new job. Maybe they won't use Thymeleaf, so I wanted to be prepared (but there are other tutorials, like those from Baeldung)

Comment: Learning JSP is no bad thing, so if it's a business requirement, then certainly learn it. I personally do use start.spring.io to create my Boot projects. Be very careful about habits that you pick up from this job; note that the tutorial is using Spring 3.0, which is _ten years old_.

Comment: Just tried Spring Boot and it's indeed great. These tutorials are pretty long and cover a lot of things, so maybe it was suggested for other topics. Fun fact: Another tutorial covered Applets. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll make sure to ask my superiors about this topic.